# making a class instance to separate and organize classes

Tags: python-3.x

I am wanting to make a Python program to help in choosing a Nerf war load out by allowing me to enter data that I get, such as how far the gun shoots, it's size, weight, type, ect.  then I want to create different functions that will allow me to pull up optimal builds such as a sniper build for example.

I made a class so I can enter all the information for each gun into it's own class.

I am not sure how to approach making a function for example "sniper" that will pull only sniper types then put them in order by how far their shooting distance is.

I am thinking about a for loop but I am not sure how to approach it.

```py
class Nerf_Gun:

    def __init__(self, name, size, weight, DPS, distance, slots, type):
        self.name = name
        self.size = size
        self.weight = weight
        self.DPS = DPS
        self.distance = distance
        self.slots = slots
        self.type = type

    def sniper(self):
        if Nerf_Gun.type() == "Sniper":
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to create different types of guns which may belong to broad categories, hence you are looking for the concept of `inheritance`. Look up https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_inheritance.asp. In general, if you are looking to make those attributes configurable for each "instance" of a gun, I would make it through `attrs`.

```
@attr.s
class Gun:
    name: str = attr.ib()
    size: int = attr.ib()
    weight: int = attr.ib()
    DPS: str = attr.ib()
    distance: str = attr.ib()
    slots: str = attr.ib()
    type: str = attr.ib()

Sniper = attr.make_class('Sniper', {}, bases=(Gun,))

#initialize instance
nerf_gun = Sniper(name='sniper', size=2, weight=3, DPS='123', distance='123', slots='456', type='789')
```

You can play around with making these attributes optional or override them in Sniper class etc.

However, if you want to keep them constant across the class (all snipers have the same values for each gun), I would initialize the class with variables, exactly like you were, but make subclasses for Sniper etc like so:

```
class Sniper(Nerf_Gun):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Sniper'
        self.weight = 123
        # fix the rest of attrs
```